# How do you access element with a custom polymer element?

Tags: polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

Given the example element.

```
<my-element>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <a href="/test">Test</a>
</my-element>
```

How would I select the `href` of the a tag?

Sorry I don't have more, I've been testing a whole bunch of things.

I know within the `<template>` if you have `<content id="a-tag" select="a">`. You should be able to go `this.$["a-tag"]` but I don't know how to access the attributes, plus then I'm stuck showing the element within the shadow DOM, which I don't want. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `this.querySelector('a').href`? `this` inside of your Polymer element methods refers to the host node (outside of Shadow DOM).

Comment: This works great! Is there any way to select innerText of a custom element without <content></content>

Answer (score 2):

[`content.getDistributedNodes()`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-301/#toc-getDistributedNodes) will get you the list of light dom nodes going through the `<content>` insertion point.

So this should work if you're using `<content select="a">`:

```
content.getDistributedNodes()[0].href
```

Note: `this.$['a-tag']` will not work . You'd need to do:

```
this.$['a-tag'].getDistributedNodes()[0].href
```

Comment: Is there any way to not show / display content in the theme, but still access it?

Comment: Still need this answered :/ ^^